# Transforming XML to valid HTML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have XML and XSL I want to transform to valid HTML. Source and targets are XmlDocuments.

I have this code:

```
public static XmlDocument XslTransformation(XslCompiledTransform xslt, XmlDocument input)
{
    XmlDocument target = new XmlDocument();

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(target.CreateNavigator().AppendChild(), xslt.OutputSettings))
    {
        xslt.Transform(input, writer);
    }

    return target;
}
```

In XSL we set output method:

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
```

But result is not valid HTML. For example

```
<script src="blah.js"></script>
```

is converted to

```
<script src="blah.js" />
```

I checked OutputMethod of XSLT OutputSettings and it is set to "Html".

I found many related questions and accepted answers but I dont understand why I am still getting self-closing tags.

Comment: Well, you create an `XmlDocument` as the result, so what do you expect? It will contain a tree of nodes and not a serialization at all where output settings matter, I suppose when you serialize/save your `XmlDocument` you magically expect it to have turned into some HTML document but that is not the case. If you want HTML output then use a File/Stream/TextWriter as the result you create. Or, where you save the target document, make sure you then save with an XmlWriter with the output settings.

Comment: I see. I was assuming Transform() method was giving HTML to me becuase XmlDocument can contain valid HTML. Original implementation was processing data in phases, first transforming to HTML, then it was retrieved back using TextWriter. Then it was read to XmlDocument again to process it more, then it was taking out OuterXml which was used as an input to next XmlDocument and repeating this cycle until document was ready. This produced correct HTML but I wanted to streamline processing and use one XmlDocument through the process. I try TextWriter after last step, maybe it helps.

Comment: Taking out final document with TextWriter and I get properly formatted HTML.